# How to sort contacts data alphabetically according name & when contact doesn't have a name, use email instead?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

I'm currently creating a simple contact app using Kotlin and MVVM Architecture, I was able to display contact's name and email address with recyclerview, but when a "Contact" doesn't have a name I want to display only the email address also sorting it alphabetically in the recyclerview either the data is a "name" or "email address".

my Goal (name, email) 
- John, john@gmail.com 
- kaila@gmail.com 
- Lee, lee@gmail.com

I've tried altering my List variable with

```
for (contact in listContacts) {
    if (contact.name == "" || contact.name.isEmpty()) {
        contact.name = contact.email
    }
}
```

but it will make contact.name to have the same value as contact.email and I don't want it. contact.name need to keep their original value which is "" or null for further feature.

I can't think of a way to resolve this issue by changing the query inside my DAO.

Answer (score 1):

For that I think you have taken two variables in your pojo and model class.

Now, For displaying Name I think you have taken a simple TextView in your raw file or a xml file for the RecyclerView's raw (adapter).

All right.

Now, You are setting the name value from **contact.name** which is correct.

But, In case If there is no value in it, You are assigning the value of **contact.email** in to **contact.name**. That's the reason the value of name is changed.

To avoid this, why you can't set the value of **contact.email** directly to your TextView as below :

```
    for (contact in listContacts) {
        if (contact.name == "" || contact.name.isEmpty()) {
            tv_user_name.setText(""+contact.email);
        }else{
            tv_user_name.setText(""+contact.name);
        }
    }
```

Here, `tv_user_name` is a TextView inside your raw file.

Simple..!

Answer (score 0):

Alphabetic sorting use `List.sortBy()`

```
list.sortBy { if (!it.name.isNullOrEmpty()) it.name else it.email }
```

Whenever `name` is not present, it will check with `email`